# How to efficiently reduce and represent a given graph to an equivalence form?

Tags: c++, graph, stl

I am struggling with an (apparently simple) undirected graph representation in c++ using stl. Normally, I would store a graph using a simple array of vectors as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vectors>
#define NODES 10
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<pair<int, int>> graph[NODES];
    int u,v, weight;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      cin>>u>>v>>weight;
      graph[u].push_back(make_pair(v,weight));
      graph[v].push_back(make_pair(u,weight));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I am finding it difficult to store the graph for the below scenario:

[image]

In the above graph, I have 2 types of edges `a` and `b`. Vertices adjacent to edge `b` **are considered a equivalent**. So, those two vertices (`2` & `6` in this case) are equivalent and they have to be merged and represented as one.

Therefore, I want to reduce and store the above graph as shown below:

[image]

NOTE: It may happen that sometimes while reducing it may violate some property. For example, if the edges **1-6** and **2-6** both have labels `b` and **1-2** has label `a` then it becomes ambigous, which one to keep. So, in such scenarios, how can I detect it and report that the graph is not valid?

So far I am thinking of storing `a` and `b` label edges seperately as two arrays of vectors then do a kind of cross checking. But this seems to be very complicated to code and very messy and would probably increase the overall complexity of the code.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Ron. Is there a way to migrate this to the suggested link? I havn't migrated any post in stackexchange so I don't know how to migrate this question.

Comment: I am not sure about migrating but I know you should avoid cross posting. Perhaps delete this one and post a new one there?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that I should avoid cross posting because I was about to copy paste the same question there. But I wouldn't do it now. Ok, got it.

Comment: You should copy paste given that you delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the edge to have more information that the two vertices it connects, you can define the edge as:

```
enum edge_type {a, b};
struct edge {
  int v1;
  int v2;
  edge_type etype;
}
```

And then represent your graph like this:

```
vector<edge> graph[NODES];
```